# javascript breaks when I want to print a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

So I created this webpage using JQuery. I use this code to resize the images on my page so that they fit in squares.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $('.square').width();
    $('.square').css('height', height); 
    window.onresize = function(event) {
      var height = $('.square').width();
      $('.square').css('height', height);
   }
 });
</script>
```

This works perfectly. The images resize to squares when I load the page or when i resize my browser window. The problem is when I go and press print page (I'm using google Chrome). The printer preview loads the page as if these two scripts don't exist. So the images are their original sizes.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Could be because `.css()` is adding inline style and probably those are screen only not print. So you have to find a way to add these styles to a print css somehow...

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep images square, you might not even need javascript, the below gives you an example, the bonus it's responsive..

```css
.pic-wrapper { 
  width: 40%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.pic { 
  width: 100%; 
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/uTDpE6J.jpg')  
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-wrapper">
  <div class="pic">    
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pic-wrapper">
  <div class="pic">    
  </div>
</div>
```